# The machine refuse to read bootable cds

Tags: windows, boot

Well I've encountered rather unusual event. I bought origianl windows 7 disk and when I inserted it into machine it didn't boot. Bios and everything is set to boot from cd. I've try on other machine it works fine. There is windows xp previously installed on the machine. I've tried to open the cd from windows explorer and it said that the disk is empty. I've tested with several other disks and the cd-rom recognize them with no problem. I tested with ubuntu live disk same problem. Disk is empty no boot. I've tried with bootable USB same problem. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really a "CD" drive, perhaps it's because Windows 7 comes on DVD.

Comment: but that doesnt make sense why ubuntu live CD would show nothing... I was thinking the same thing though.

Comment: It's a dvd-rom and dvd drive. The problem is with both mediums if they are bootable

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your CD/DVD Drive. Have you tried removing the drive and replacing it with one that is currently working?

Comment: The could you explain why there is a problem with bootable usb. I have computer for 12 years and this case is like no other before.

Comment: It **could** be an issue. I never said it was an issue, and also, if you are having issues booting with a USB, then you should check out the BIOS. See if either of those mediums are allowed to booted from.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the back of the dvd, does it have any scratches, or dust/dirt?
Try cleaning it with a clean cloth first.

if that doesn't improve things.did you buy your copy of windows from a reputable vendor?
it's possible that have been scammed either intentionally or unintentionally.

IF cleaning the dvd doesn't work and you're comfortable with who you purchased from, 
try contacting Microsoft Support.

Since you purchased your copy and are just trying to install it; you should be able to go thru microsoft support free of charge.

It's also possible that the format of the microsoft dvd isn't compatible with your dvd drive -you might need to update firmware on your dvd).

Your best option is probably to try Microsoft Support who can also probably help you with updating your dvd drive firmware if that's necessary.

Comment: The machine don't read any bootable disks. Linux, windows, none of them. As I said I made bootable usb and no success. It refuse any bootable device, and all bootable disk are empty for windows explorer